# How to get any but the last match in a nested capturing group?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following example:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.(,(.))*)/|$1|$2|$3|/' <<<a,b,c
|a,b,c|,c|c|
```

How to access any but he last match in the nested capturing group? In this example the nested capturing group captures only `c`. How to reference `b`?

Comment: Regex capture groups only capture a single match (the last one) when they are repeating (like with `*`, you need to use another approach for repeating patterns, there is one with `\G` and `\K` that you can use.

Comment: Adding to Mike's comment, something really fast: `\G,?\K([^,]+)`. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tV4oY9). Btw, why not just split by `,`?

Comment: @HamZa Maybe I have striped the example too much. There is more at the beginning and at the end which prevents splitting.

Comment: ceving could you give a slightly more in depth solution, so that we can give you a proper answer, @Hamza's suggestion is the best I can come up with or scanning a string for every one of a few matches but it depends on what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, I suspect you haven't shown a representative example. But the obvious way is to ensure that the captured character is followed by a comma, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'a,b,c';

$s =~ s/(.(,(.(?=,)))*)/|$1|$2|$3|/;

print $s;
```

**output**

```
|a,b|,b|b|,c
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if there is data before and after the example, you can still rely on `split`.  You just need to use multiple steps.

The following demonstrates that for a randomly constructed example:

```
echo '<start>a,b,c<end>' | perl -pe 's/<start>\K(.*?)(?=<end>)/"|" . join("|", split ",", $1) . "|"/e'
```

Outputs:

```
<start>|a|b|c|<end>
```